# What is the difference between offering access to an API through the context or offering it through a parameter?

Tags: javascript

Given the following API:

```
SomeAPI = (function() {
  var secretKey = 'passw0rd',
      foo = 'foo',
      bar = 'bar';
  return {
    use : function(callback) { /* Provide the API to the callback */ }
  };
})();
```

It consists of a couple values and most importantly is used through its `use()` public method, which allows users to consume the API through a callback.
The callback can access the API in one of two ways:

### 1) Through `this`

`callback` is either [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)ed or [`appl[i]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)ed. Consuming the API is done with `this`:

```
SomeAPI.use(function() {
  doStuffWith(this.foo);
});
```

### 2) Through a parameter

`callback` is simply invoked with a parameter containing the API. Consuming the API is done with the given parameter:

```
SomeAPI.use(function(api) {
  doStuffWith(api.bar);
});
```

---

I've seen both patterns used. Is there any practical difference between the two? Something possible with one but not the other?

Comment: It's just passing an object, much like passing an element that you then call methods on. BTW, I don't think you'll get a definitive answer one way or the other. The module pattern (first one) is more common with singletons, the second with inherited methods. But popular libraries, for example, use both.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any practical difference between the two? Something possible with one but not the other?

I'm sure there are many, but I'll detail the most important differences as far as I can tell.

For the first example, assign the variables to a private object, then assign the private object to the value of `this` for the callback.

The good part about this is that we are actually passing a reference to the private object, so we can alter that object.

The bad part about this is that we are actually passing a reference to the private object, so users can alter that object willy nilly, which is never a good thing.

```js
SomeAPI = (function() {
    var private = {};
    private.secretKey = 'passw0rd';
    private.foo = 'foo';
    private.bar = 'bar';
    return {
        use : function(callback) { callback.call(private); }
    };
})();

console.log(SomeAPI.private); 
// undefined

SomeAPI.use(function(){
    console.log(this.secretKey, this.foo, this.bar); 
    // passw0rd foo bar
    console.log(this.constructor); 
    // Object() { [native code] }
    console.log(this);
    // Object {secretKey: "passw0rd", foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}
    this.hello = 'world';
    this.foo = 'bar';
    this.bar = 'foo';
});

SomeAPI.use(function(){
    console.log(this.secretKey, this.foo, this.bar, this.hello);
    // passw0rd bar foo world
    console.log(this);
    // Object {secretKey: "passw0rd", foo: "bar", bar: "foo", hello: "world"}
});
```

Let's take stock of what this shows us.

1. The private object is in fact private.
2. `this` refers to the private object.
3. `this` contains all of the private properties.
4. Any changes to the private object persist to the next API call.

---

For the second example, we pass the values of each private property to the callback.

The good part about this method is the downfall of the previous method. This method locks everything down so only what you explicitly allow to be changed/accessed can be changed/accessed.

The bad part about this method is that you're locked into what is defined by the API.

```js
OtherAPI = (function() {
    var secretKey = 'passw0rd',
        foo = 'foo',
        bar = 'bar';
    return {
        use : function(callback) { callback(secretKey, foo, bar); },
        setFoo : function(val) { foo = val },
        setBar : function(val) { bar = val }
    };
})();

console.log(OtherAPI.foo);
// undefined

OtherAPI.use(function(secretKey, foo, bar){
    console.log(secretKey, foo, bar);
    // passw0rd foo bar
    console.log(this.constructor);
    // Window() { [native code] }
    foo = 'bar';
    bar = 'foo';
    console.log(secretKey, foo, bar);
    // passw0rd bar foo
});

OtherAPI.use(function(secretKey, foo, bar){
    console.log(secretKey, foo, bar);
    // passw0rd foo bar
});

OtherAPI.setFoo('bar');
OtherAPI.setBar('foo');

OtherAPI.use(function(secretKey, foo, bar){
    console.log(secretKey, foo, bar);
    // passw0rd bar foo
});
```

Ok, so what does this show us?

1. The private properties are in fact private
2. We can read the values of the private properties via the supplied arguments only.
3. Any changes made to the callback's arguments *do **not*** persist to the next API call.
4. If we define functions inside the returned API object to change the private property's values we can change individual values. These changes *do* persist to the next API call.

---

And finally one more example that is, sort of, a compromise between the two and, if done right, can be more versatile than either of the previous examples.

The good part about this method is that you can protect what you want to protect, and choose how the user can access the private variables.

The bad part about this method is that you really have to think about how the user might try to abuse the get and set functions in order

```js
OtherAPI = (function() {
    var private = {};
    private.secretKey = 'passw0rd';
    private.foo = 'foo';
    private.bar = 'bar';
    private.noaccess = 'No Access!';
    return {
        use : function(callback) { callback.call(this); },
        get : function(prop) { 
            if(private[prop] && prop != 'noaccess') return private[prop];
            return false;
        },
        set : function(prop, val) { 
            if(private[prop] && prop != 'noaccess') return (private[prop] = val);
            return false;
        },
        noaccess : function() { return private.noaccess }
    };
})();

console.log(OtherAPI.secretKey);
// undefined
console.log(OtherAPI.get('secretKey'));
// passw0rd

OtherAPI.use(function(){
    console.log(this.get('secretKey'), this.get('foo'), this.get('bar'), this.get('noaccess'), this.noaccess());
    // passw0rd foo bar false No Access!
    console.log(this.constructor);
    // Object() { [native code] }
    // The above object is actually the public scope, not the private scope
    this.set('foo', 'bar');
    this.set('bar', 'foo');
    this.hello = 'world'; // This will be in the public scope
    console.log(this.get('secretKey'), this.get('foo'), this.get('bar'), this.get('noaccess'), this.noaccess(), this.hello);
    // passw0rd bar foo false No Access! world
});

OtherAPI.use(function(secretKey, foo, bar){
    console.log(this.get('secretKey'), this.get('foo'), this.get('bar'), this.get('noaccess'), this.noaccess(), this.hello);
    // passw0rd bar foo false No Access! world
});
```

What does this example show us?

1. Same as before, private is private.
2. `this` refers to the public object (the object returned to OtherAPI)
3. We can now *set* or *get* any of the private properties, as long as they currently exists and we haven't explicitly denied access to that variable.
4. You can also further control what private properties can be set or retrieved, and how that happens.

This means that your API could be more secure than the first example, while having more flexibility than the second example and, with added security checks in the set and get functions, it can be as secure or more secure than the second example.

In the end it all depends on how much you trust the users of your API, and how much you want to protect the private properties.

Comment: This is concentrated awesomeness. I have a few remarks: A result similar to the second example could be achieved in the first example by generating a new object and passing the primitive values: `.call({foo : private.foo, ...})`, and the reverse is true in the 2nd if you define the values on an object (passing only one paramater, `callback(private)`. In the third example, wouldn't managing the private values be even funnier if one used `Symbol.for`? `private[Symbol.for('noaccess')] = true` would mean `noaccess` is private, and this could be retrieved in `get()` with `private[Symbol.for(prop)]`

Answer (score 0):

In functions the `this` object can refer to anything from a multitude of objects. It all comes down to how the given function is called, and is exactly what the first argument to [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is.

Consider the following example:

```
var fn = function (api) {
    doStuffWith(this.foo);
    doStuffWith(api.foo);
};
```

Both `doStuffWith` calls receive the same argument, the same string object when you invoke `fn` in the following way:

```
SomeAPI.use(function(api) {
    fn.apply(api, [api]);
});
```

Other than this (no pun intended), it is entirely up to the API naming conventions and the best applicable logic. Both versions point (refer) exactly to the same object, use what results in more verbose and clean-looking code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this